# Update a column with a value from another database

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update

I am using PostgreSQL and I want to update a column with a value from another column of another database. The two databases are in the same PostgreSQL server.

Is this possible? please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Use a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) or the [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) module

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name it's so nice of you =)